# $R^1$ is First Category as a subset of $R^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category, complete-spaces

Exercise 3.4.5 of Avner Friedman's Foundations of Modern Analysis asks the following question

> A set $Y$ in metric $X$ is first category in $X$ if it is contained in a countable union of nowhere dense sets of $X$. If $Y$ is not first category, it is second category. The real line with Euclidean metric is a space of the 2nd category. Prove, however, that as a subset of the Euclidean plain, the real line is a set of first category.

And here is my summary of why this true, and where I get stuck.

$R^1$ is second category clearly since it is a complete metric space and all complete metric spaces are 2nd category. Now consider $R^1\subseteq R^2=\{(a,b): a,n\in R\}$ where $R^1=\{(a,0): a\in R\}$. We want to show that $R^1$ is contained in a countable union of nowhere dense sets of $R^2$. That is, we want to show $R^1\subseteq S=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty T_j$ where $T_j$'s are nowhere dense, i.e. $\overline{T_j}$ has no interior points.

Essentially what we need to see is that $R^1$ is not complete in $R^2$, meaning that we can find a Cauchy sequence in $R^1$ that has its limit in $R^2- R^1$.

So then I started thinking about this and started losing all hope for any understand that I had about what it means for a set to be dense verses nowhere dense. I could really use some help to see how to finish this proof, or help on really understanding these two concepts and how they are different. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No. That $R^1$ is a set of the first category in $R^2$ does ***not*** mean that i's not complete. The line is  ***nowhere dense closed set*** in the plane, and ***that*** is why it's first category. The line is a closed set (so it's complete, a Cauchy sequence in $R^1$ has its limit in $R^1.$ It's nowhere dense because the interior of the closure of the line is just the interior of the line, which is empty.

Comment: This comment makes sense, but can you explain why the interior of the line is empty? Thanks!

Comment: An open subset of the plane contains an open disc about each of its points. Therefore a nonempty open subset of the plane contains a disc, and any subset of the plane with nonempty interior contains a disc. Can you prove that a line does in the plane contains no disc?

Comment: I see why your claim is true, I don't know if I can prove it to you in an elegant way though. If you try to take a disk around a single point on a line, you will end up with points in that disk that are not on the line, maybe they lie above or below it but not on it. For instance if $r=\frac{1}{2}$ then you will get any point that  y in $R^2$ Such that $d(x,y)<1/2$

Comment: Why do you need proof? Isn't it enough that you know it's true?

Comment: Yea, but one of my biggest problems in this class is that I don't write out my proofs in a rigorous way. And my final is 10 days away, so I'm trying to work on my proof writing now :)

Answer (score 6):

$\mathbb{R}$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$, as it is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and has an empty interior. In particular, it is of the first category (if you want a countably infinite union of nowhere dense sets, take $\mathbb{R}$ together with the empty set countably many times).